# Vlookup in excel for 2 sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am having 2 sheets
Sheet 1 :

```
LAST_NAME   FIRST_NAME  WINDOWS_LOGIN
Adnan            Aamir      aadnan
```

Next sheet  2 :

```
DisplayName      Name          SamAccountName
adnan,aamir    adnan,aamir      aadnan
```

How do I match the list according to windows login name & samAccountname and get the output.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to use the `WINDOWS_LOGIN` to return values to the left, `Vlookup()` won't work. Look into [`Index/Match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/).

Comment: What output are you looking for? And based on which parameters?

Comment: what do you want to output?

Comment: Thanks for replying , I am looking to get the windows_login(names) that are present in the sheet 2 samAccountname(its a huge list). output can be the name itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VLOOKUP and later check if it returns #N/A or not. If it doesn't, the record exists.

So for example create a new column on Sheet1 named PRESENT_SHEET2 and put the following formula in D2:
`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2;Sheet2!C:C;1;FALSE));FALSE;TRUE)`